# Finding $f(z)$ given the harmonic real part of $f$ (why can they relabel $x$ as $z$?)

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

Given that $u$ is harmonic where $$u(x,y):= \frac{x(x^2 + y^2 + 1)}{(x^2 + y^2)^2 + 2(x^2 - y^2) + 1}$$
find an analytic function $f$ where $u$ is the real part of $f$.

This is what my notes does and I'm not sure why/how it works.

I thought I'd have to consider CRE, integrating $v_y = u_x$ w.r.t $y$, differentiate w.r.t $x$ and equate to find $v$.

However, this is what they did:
$$u(x,y) = \frac{x(x^2 + y^2 + 1)}{(x^2 + y^2)^2 + 2(x^2 - y^2) + 1} \\ u(x,0) = \frac{x}{x^2 + 1}$$
Note that $f'(x+iy) = u_x - iu_y$ and this is true at $y=0$.
So at $(x,0)$, noting that $u_y (x,0) = 0$,
$$f'(x) = \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\frac{x}{x^2 + 1} + i0$$
hence,
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2 + 1}$$
and so
$$f(z) = \frac{z}{z^2 + 1}.$$

Can someone explain this solution (esp. the part of finding $u(x,0)$ and then relabelling $x$ as $z$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f'(x+yi)=u_x(x,y)-u_y(x,y)i$ and if $u_y(x,0)=0$, then $f'(x)=u_x(x,0)$. So $f(z)=\frac z{z^2+1}$ when $z\in\mathbb R$. The identity theorem lets you deduce that $f(z)=\frac z{z^2+1}$ everywhere.